# Relative position in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Im trying to make a body move when you touch the screen. Left if you touch left from the sprite and right if you touch right.
The bug i have is that that the body only moves a distance equal to the distance of the touch from the Sprite.

And the way to fix this i understand is by modifing the touch event by the current camera position

In all the following code `walkingActivate=true;`

*Sprite onManageUpdate*

```
 @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            if(walkingActivate) {
                if (mActivity.touchedForWaling) {

                    if (!characterImage.isAnimationRunning()) {
                        characterImage.animate(new long[]{200,200,200,200,200},new int[]{1,2,3,4,5},true);
                    }
                    move(mActivity.SceneTouchEvent);
                }
                else{
                    characterImage.stopAnimation();
                    characterImage.setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                }
            }

        }
```

*Relevant code*

```
public void move(TouchEvent event){
    float movement=.05f;
    if (event.getX()+mActivity.mCamera.getXMin()<characterImage.getX()){
        movement=-.05f;
        characterImage.setFlippedHorizontal(true);
    }
    else {characterImage.setFlippedHorizontal(false);}
    PlayerBody.setTransform(PlayerBody.getPosition().x+movement,PlayerBody.getPosition().y,0);
}
```

*Part of Scene listener*

```
if(currentPlayer.walkingActivate) {
                    mCamera.setChaseEntity(currentPlayer.characterImage);
                    if((!currentPlayer.onAir)&&(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()||pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove())){
                        SceneTouchEvent= pSceneTouchEvent;
                        Log.d("DEBUG","TouchEvent changed");
                        //this will trigger the walking action in the Sprite onUpdate
                        touchedForWaling =true;

                    }
                    else {touchedForWaling =false;}
```

The XMin method is not working so i dont know what else to try (besides `getCenterX()-getWithd/2`

Comment: so you want to touch right of the sprite, and as long as you keep it touched you want sprite to move right? Untill you stop touching screen? Same for moving left? Am I right?

Comment: agan move your sprite in onManagedUpdate by adding `movement` to sprite `getX()` as long as boolean value of some variable is true. For example `boolean moveRight = true` when you touch screen and only once you check if TouchEvent.getX() is bigger then Sprite.getX(). then your sprite will move right until touchEvent.isActionUp() in which you change moveRight to false. One thing though - it will not work properly if you want to swipe from left to right of the sprite.

Comment: this method is actually performed in onManageUpdate.But maybe the code is actually confusing, i will post the other parts. Besides that i actually want to work with swipe

Comment: I thought so, Is camera following your sprite? (chaseEntity)

Comment: hello? Anyone, please!